# Storyboard doesn't work

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to rotate as well as enlarge and then shrink a TextBlock. I want to use Stroyboard and write the code in code-behind file.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Name="rotatingTextBlock" Text="Hello" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" World!"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

..

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TransformGroup tc = new TransformGroup();
    RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    tc.Children.Add(rotateTransform);
    ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
    tc.Children.Add(scaleTransform);

    rotatingTextBlock.RenderTransform = tc;

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 360, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
    rotateAnimation.AccelerationRatio = 0.15;
    rotateAnimation.DecelerationRatio = 0.15;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, rotateTransform);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath(RotateTransform.AngleProperty));
    storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);

    DoubleAnimation scaleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 1.2, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    scaleAnimation.AccelerationRatio = 0.5;
    scaleAnimation.DecelerationRatio = 0.5;
    scaleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, scaleTransform);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));
    storyboard.Children.Add(scaleAnimation);

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

My code doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you have to set the TextBlock as Animations Target: `Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, rotatingTextBlock);`. You could also create your Storyboard in xaml and call it in Code-Behind with `((Storyboard)FindResource("SBName")).Begin();`

Comment: Well, your insight helps. Thank you! But I'd like to know why I cannot set RotateTransform as the target.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Storyboard.SetTarget only works on UIElements, but throws no exception](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/723701/storyboard-settarget-only-works-on-uielements-but-throws-no-exception) it seems that you can not target a `Transform` directly. If you target the `TextBlock` with the right `PropertyPath` it works:

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 360, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
rotateAnimation.AccelerationRatio = 0.15;
rotateAnimation.DecelerationRatio = 0.15;
Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, rotatingTextBlock);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);

DoubleAnimation scaleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 1.2, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
scaleAnimation.AccelerationRatio = 0.5;
scaleAnimation.DecelerationRatio = 0.5;
scaleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, rotatingTextBlock);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
storyboard.Children.Add(scaleAnimation);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 360, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
rotateAnimation.AccelerationRatio = 0.15;
rotateAnimation.DecelerationRatio = 0.15;
try { UnregisterName("rotateTransform"); }
catch { }
finally { RegisterName("rotateTransform", rotateTransform); }
Storyboard.SetTargetName(rotateAnimation, "rotateTransform");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath(RotateTransform.AngleProperty));
storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);

DoubleAnimation scaleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 1.2, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
scaleAnimation.AccelerationRatio = 0.5;
scaleAnimation.DecelerationRatio = 0.5;
scaleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
try { UnregisterName("scaleTransform"); }
catch { }
finally { RegisterName("scaleTransform", scaleTransform); }
Storyboard.SetTargetName(scaleAnimation, "scaleTransform");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));
storyboard.Children.Add(scaleAnimation);

storyboard.Begin(this);
```

However, I tried LPL's solution and that also works - and if LPL's method would work for any "abstract" target, then I think I much prefer it as a solution (to save registering names, etc.). (The problem is I have no idea how to put together those property paths!)